# Remove li child by a specific data-gt

Tags: javascript, html

Ok I have this HTML code:

```
<ul>    
    <li data-gt="{'alert_id':11111,'type':'hello'}"></li>
    <li data-gt="{'alert_id':11111,'type':'bye'}"></li>
    <li data-gt="{'alert_id':11111,'type':'hello'}"></li>
    <li data-gt="{'alert_id':11111,'type':'bye'}"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to delete all **li** tags containing **"type":"hello"**. And I want to be counted all deleted tags, in a **var**.
*PS: I can't change HTML code.*

We looked everywhere, but fail, if possible in JavaScript. (not jQuery). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: This will fail as you're opening and closing a quote for the attribute and the start of your JSON.

Comment: I played with this function
var elem = document.getElementById('id');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

Comment: Are the quotes correct? just `"` and no `'` ?This is invalid HTML

Comment: Sorry for quotes, i change them.

Comment: I see you've used single quotes inside the attribute. Mind you that makes the content non JSON-valid (you should use double quotes), if that was your intent.

Comment: Sorry if I'm removing my answer. I'm sure it worked, but it's not the accepted one, and I don't want downvotes from someone who doesn't even bother to show up and explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correct the HTML tags, and then filter your Nodes and parse the JSON:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gt]');
var deletedNodes = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var self = elems[i];
    var attr = self.getAttribute('data-gt');
    var parseAttr = JSON.parse(attr);
    if (parseAttr.type === 'hello') {
        self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
        deletedNodes++;
    }
}

// log deleted nodes
console.log(deletedNodes); // 2
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/tT8HW/

This code parses your data-attribute and then checks the object value. This is going to be far more accurate and extendable.

Comment: Don't forget to count the deleted nodes in a var.

Comment: Working! You are the best! How can i count deleted nodes? I used i but that give me all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code should look like this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-gt='{"alert_id":11111,"type":"hello"}'></li>
  <li data-gt='{"alert_id":11111,"type":"bye"}'></li>
  <li data-gt='{"alert_id":11111,"type":"hello"}'></li>
  <li data-gt='{"alert_id":11111,"type":"bye"}'></li>
</ul>
```

And here is javascript:

```
var items = document.getElementById('list').children;
var remCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var json = items[i].getAttribute('data-gt');
  try {
    var data = eval('(' + json + ')');
    if (data.type === 'hello') {
      items[i].parentNode.removeChild(items[i]);
      remCount++;
     }
  } catch(e) {

  }
}
console.log('Removed ' + remCount + ' elements');
```

This should work in all browsers

**Edit**

It's better to use `JSON.parse(json)` instead of `eval('(' + json + ')')`, but it doesn't work in IE7

Comment: Eval and try catches seem rather overkill here.

Comment: The problem with this is that malicious code could be bound to that attribute, then pulled into the eval() method. Best to avoid it, and since the user didn't specify any browser support, I've gone with the lowest risk option :)! Plus JSON.parse() is much faster! Happy coding.